# How can I add vw to the hight with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do something like the below. Get the .content height and then add that height plus 27vw to .container height.

Is this at all possible?

```
let imageHeight = $('.content').height();
$('.container').css('height', imageHeight - '27vw');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`calc` CSS function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc()) to add `27vw` to the element's height:

```js
let imageHeight = $('.content').height();
$('.container').css('height', `calc(${imageHeight}px + 27vw)`);
```

```css
.container{
  background-color:grey;
}

.content{
  height:1vw;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="container"></div>
```